# Manipulate multiple lines between 2 delimiter lines (append if not exist else replace)

Tags: linux, awk, text, sed, command-line

In linux, I see a lot of programs add things to my rc files between their own start and end delimiter patterns. For example, with conda:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/tidu/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2>/dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/tidu/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/tidu/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/tidu/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

I want to do the same thing for some of my configs.

```
# dynamic start pattern
dynamic
body
# dynamic end pattern
```

dynamic means that the content may be generated dynamically, not hard coded in the script.

I tried a lot but is yet to find out a clean way to do this seemingly very common thing. Please show me how to do this with some commandline tools like `awk`, `sed` or `perl`.

Comment: You can just use `printf` with the shell itself in most cases to modify files with dynamic patterns.

Answer (score 1):

With all these utilities it is quite simple to cut the original file in 3 parts:

- From beginning to start delimiter (excluded).
- From start to end delimiters (included).
- From end delimiter (excluded) to the end.

Replacing the middle part is then easy. Example with `awk`, assuming the text to update is prepared in bash variable `str`, and awk variables `start` and `end` contain the regular expressions that match the start and end delimiter lines:

```
# foo.awk
$0 ~ start {
    if(n != 0) {
        n = 3
        exit
    }
    n = 1
}
n == 0 || n == 2 {
    print
}
$0 ~ end {
    if(n != 1) {
        n = 3
        exit
    }
    print str
    n = 2
}
n == 1 {
    next
}
END {
    if(n != 0 && n != 2) {
        print "error"
        exit 1
    } else if(n == 0) {
        print str
    }
}
```

```sh
$ start='# dynamic start pattern'
$ end='# dynamic end pattern'
$ str="\
$start
dynamic
body
$end"
$ awk -v str="$str" -v start="^$start\$" -v end="^$end\$" -f foo.awk foo.rc > new.rc
```

The most complicated part is detecting errors (start and end in reverse order, one start but no end, one end but no start, more than one start or end...) The `n` awk variable is used to keep track of the current state: before start (`n=0`), after end (`n=2`), in between (`n=1`) or error (`n=3`). If an error occurs `awk` exits with status 1. Else, if it exits with status 0, you can replace the old rc file by the new one.